# How to exclude a div (flex item) from flex calculations?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an html layout that I cannot modify since it's a 3d party library.

I have four divs and I want them to be inside a flexbox like that:

1------2------3

(where 2 is in the center and 4 is not visible at all).

I have created an example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqyrxq).

It seems that it mostly work as I want to apart from the fact that the last div messes up the center position of the item number 2. Is there a way I can completely "exclude" it from the flex array by css even though it is in HTML?

```css
.fc-toolbar {
 background-color: #7CC2DD;
 color: white;
 height: 5rem;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.fc-left {
 order: 0; 
}

.fc-right {
 order: 2;
}

.fc-center {
 order: 1;
}

.fc-clear {

}
```

```html
<div class="fc-toolbar">
  <div class="fc-left">
    <button type="button">
      <
    </button></div>
  <div class="fc-right">
    <button type="button">
          >
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="fc-center">
    <h2>May 2016</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: keep min-widths of all divs as 33% and put flex-wrap: nowrap; and keep the overflow for the container as hidden..this will not give enuf room for the 4 to come into the box and 2 will get centered.

Answer (score 20):

You can give the element `position: absolute` and it will be taken out of the flow, just as you would do with a non-flex element.

You can find the updated jsfiddle [here](http://codepen.io/fabiosang/pen/vXdqQq).

Comment: The url to the link is pointing to codepen (not jsfiddle) which is giving a 404 error.